# Android select one row from a database error

Tags: android

I am new to Android and trying to select a row from a database like this:

```
public Cursor getEntry(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor entry = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{
            "id", "title", "description", "image_path"
    }, "id" + "=?", new String[]{ String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

    return entry;
}
```

and trying to output it like this:

```
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    if (db.getEntry(1) != null){
        while (db.getEntry(1).moveToFirst()){
            tv.setText("" + db.getEntry(1).getString(1));
        }
    }
    setContentView(tv);
```

and the error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.untitled1/com.example.untitled1.DisplayMessageActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    at com.example.untitled1.DisplayMessageActivity.onCreate(DisplayMessageActivity.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    ... 11 more
```

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: First get a good book about Java, and when you're finished, read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (db.getEntry(1).moveToFirst()){
    tv.setText("" + db.getEntry(1).getString(1));
```

You are executing the query twice, each time you execute `db.getEntry(1)`. So the second time, you are calling `getString(1)` on a different Cursor which has not been correctly set up with `moveToFirst()`.

Just call it once, and store the resulting Cursor in a local variable. Also, don't forget to close the cursor safely when you're finished.

```
Cursor c = db.getEntry(1);
try {
    if (c.moveToFirst()) 
        tv.setText(c.getString(1));
} finally {
    c.close();
}
```

Comment: @m0skit0 Dunno, it was in the original question.

Comment: You can safely remove that, it's useless. And he's executing the query not 2 but 3 times in fact...

Comment: +1 for finally but now you forgot one brace :) And Wahtever, never do that, that's way slower than `String.valueOf(notAstring)` (although slightly longer to type).

Comment: Oops, fixed the extra brace as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Wahtever I've seen a lot of Java new programmers do that "" + whatever to convert to String. That's way slower and consumes more memory than a plain and simple `String.valueOf(notAstring)` (although slightly shorter to type)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

db.getEntry(1) calling twice will return another Cursor, so it won't move to firstRow when you call `moveToFirst()` on first Cursor and accessing second

```
Cursor cursor=db.getEntry(1);

if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{
 tv.setText("" + cursor.getString(1));
}
```

Note: query method never return Cursor as Null. so no need to check for Null.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to do the query once, why you're calling `getEntry()` several times? And `while(cursor.moveToFirst())` makes no sense, it is an infinite loop if the `Cursor` has results.

```
Cursor cursor = getEntry(1);
try {
    if (cursor.moveToNext()){
       tv.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close(); // Close the Cursor when you're finished with it, or use a Loader.
}
```